# jQuery serialize error in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm currently having an issue with the jQuery method `serialize()` with internet explorer, it's working fine in the other browsers.

First, I store the form in a variable.

```
var oForm = document.forms["couponForm"];
```

Then I serialize it and pass it as a parameter to the ajax call.

```
new Ajax.Request(sURL, { asynchronous : false, method : 'post',
                parameters : oForm.serialize(true),
                onComplete : function(p_oRequest){

                },
                onException : function(p_oRequest, p_oException) {
                    throw p_oException;
                },
                onLoaded : function() {}
                });
```

However, I'm receiving an error in the internet explorer console.

SCRIPT438: object doesn't support property or method serialize.

Is serialize supposed to be supported by IE?

Comment: You're calling a jQuery method on an object that is not a jQuery object.

Comment: Shouldn't it give me an error in every browser if it's not a jQuery object? I would think if it's an error with jQuery that it would fail everywhere but it's only with IE.

Comment: @jmoerdyk Could you post your comment as an answer? This is how I corrected the issue, I used `var oForm = $("couponForm");` instead of `var oForm = document.forms["couponForm"];` and it corrected the problem with IE.

Answer (score 2):

The form should be named as **couponForm**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="couponForm">
</form>
```

Please check whether there is comma(,) or not in the Requests. There must not be any comma after the finishing of the last item. Its a strict check for the Internet Explorer.

Dont use comma after the last item

```
{ 
asynchronous : false, 
method : 'post',
parameters : oForm.serialize(true),//Dont use comma here
}
```

Use without comma instead

```
{ 
asynchronous : false, 
method : 'post',
parameters : oForm.serialize(true)//The last item must not be ended with a comma.
}
```

Comment: I had forgotten the last line of the ajax call, I've edited my question to include it. There is another item after the parameters.

Comment: I can see that the line is still incomplete:
new Ajax.Request(sURL, { asynchronous : false, method : 'post',
                parameters : oForm.serialize(true),
                onComplete : function(p_oRequest)
});

Can you please write the complete line?

Comment: I've added the complete ajax request.

Comment: Can you please post the form named "couponForm" also?

Comment: The form should be named as "couponForm".

Comment: This is the form, it is named couponForm as it should. `<form id="couponForm" name="couponForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`